# facing problems with firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I added a project in firebase.com and the project name is depthreactproject later, I activated the email verification to test this signInWithEmailAndPassword.
later I got the configuration file and copied it to my project and tried to test the login page.
also, I installed firebase to my project using npm -i install firebase
While testing this. I am facing some problems.
I used this link for the firebase reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

**Below is my Login.js**

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
//import {firebase} from './Firbase/firebase';


export default function Login() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    function handleForm(e){
        setIsLoading(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log("submitted");
        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "krishna@email.com", "password")
        .then((userCredential) => {
              // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log("this is the handleForm UserCredentials"+ userCredential);
            console.log("this is the handleForm"+ user);
            // ...
        })

    }
    return ( 
      <div className="flex h-screen bg-gray-200">  
          <div className="m-auto w-1/3 text-white flex flex-wrap justify-center shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-900 to-indigo-700">            
            <form className="m-5 w-10/12" onSubmit={handleForm}>
                <h1 className="w-full text-4xl tracking-widest text-center my-6">
                    Login
                </h1>  

                <div className="w-full my-6">
                  <input type="email"
                          className="p-2 rounded shadow w-full text-black"
                          placeholder="Email or Username"
                          name="email"/>
                </div>

                <div className="w-full my-6">
                  <input type="password"
                          className="p-2 rounded shadow w-full text-black"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          name="password"/>
                </div>

                <div className="w-full my-10">
                  <button type="submit"
                          className="p-2 rounded shadow w-full from-yellow-600 bg-yellow-400 text-black">
                    Login
                  </button>
                  
                </div>

            </form>  

          </div>
  
        </div> 
    );
  }
```

**Below is my firebase config file firebase.js**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
 import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
 import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
//import firebase from 'firebase';
//import {firebase} from "firebase";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDSGb9hlNXuQ7MmKWofDXUfFHogdREMAuA",
        authDomain: "depthreactproject.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "depthreactproject",
        storageBucket: "depthreactproject.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "176522789506",
        appId: "1:176522789506:web:bc1ccc31d95a5d221a6a9b"
    };
  
 

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    export const auth = getAuth(app);
    // firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // export {firebase}
```

I am adding the screenshot, In this, when I clk on the login button it should capture the credentials, which are static already configure in login.js, But when I change some line or comment out then only it is visible but with null value, But I should caputure it.

[image: Below is the image]

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Can you share any screenshots of errors?

Comment: sure, let me share

Comment: @Dharmaraj-> here is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnK4C.png of pic

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what exact issue is.. aren't there any errors? When does the issue show up? At any specific block of code?

Comment: @Dharmaraj->  const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "krishna@email.com", "password")
        .then((userCredential) => {
              // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log("this is the handleForm UserCredentials"+ userCredential);
            console.log("this is the handleForm"+ user);

Comment: That might be helpful, you can also try adding a `catch()` to `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to log any errors.

Comment: @Dharmaraj->sure,I added but not catching anything https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-nightingale-3qrrnt?file=/src/App.js:56-67

Comment: Is this the error that you get? "Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()"

Comment: @dharmaraj -> Here is my updated link of sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-nightingale-3qrrnt?file=/src/App.js . could you please help me now how to make my program works

Comment: @Dharmaraj, Could you please help me?

Comment: I don't see any issue in that code. I tried login in your codesandbox and it does log user information after login. This line `console.log("this is the handleForm" + JSON.stringify(user));` works. Try wrapping user in `JSON.stringify()` on your end and try?

Comment: Dharmaraj-> where should I add this line :  console.log("this is the handleForm" + JSON.stringify(user));  and JSON.stringify() could you please modify changes in codesandbox. That will be very helpfull to me. you just comment line like I made changes here please...., I am working on this very long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Login.js

import app from '../config/firebase'


// Login.js line 11
const auth = getAuth(app);
try {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "krishna@email.com", "password").then(
     (userCredential) => {
          // Signed in
          alert("signed in")
          const user = userCredential.user;

          console.log("this is the handleForm" + user);
          // ...
        }
      );
    } 
   catch (err) {
      alert("error")
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
    }
```

You have to import the initialized `app` from your `firebase.js` file and use `getAuth(app)` to start using authentication.

Instead of passing `krishna@email.com` and `password` in the sign-in method, you can use the `useRef` hook to get the value of the username, password input box and pass them.

Do not share your firebase credentials.

Comment: I am sorry for responding late, my system suddenly not working well :( .Now, I am getting this error .ERROR in ./src/page/Login.js 14:25-28     
export 'default' (imported as 'app') was not found in '../config/firebase' (possible exports: auth)

Comment: @Dharmaraj -> still getting the same pic in my browser as well as I mentioned in question :( my bad

Comment: @Dharmaraj once please help me to make it work

Comment: @rupapayal Make sure you export `app` in firebase.js . `export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

Comment: @sabz-> yes, I did it after that it should show cedentials in inspection-> netwok-> In network it should display a HTTP link with cedentials, but not working out